# Cannot replace with newlines when using sed on Mac command line

Tags: bash, curl, sed

I have a curl API response where when I get the response, I can't replace the `<br>`'s with an \n.  When I try this it outputs a literal n in the text.

What I'm doing is the curl command along with `| sed -e 's/<br>/\r\n/g'`

But no new lines and I only see n's where the `br`'s were.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, this works for me in Linux in bash: `echo "hello<br>world" | sed 's/<br>/\r\n/g'`. What operating system are you using? By the way, `sed` is not the right tool to parse HTML.

Comment: I'm on a mac.  What would be the best way to replace the br's with newlines so I can output in text to read within the command line output.

Comment: Try using a real newline, not the escape sequences.

Comment: Have you tried: `sed 's/<br>/\n/g'` ?

Comment: I realize you selected an answer, but that seems a bit strange. Try putting the command in a Bash script and see what happens, that may eliminate any shell weirdness in your environment.

Comment: OSX's default version of sed does not allow escapes in the replacement section of a substitution command. The command worked on Linux because GNU sed _does_ allow this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second attempt at an answer (the `-E` flag has saved me many times, but not this time.) Apparently newlines don't work at all in the replacement text, but this solution uses Bash's string processing (hence the `$''` syntax) to pass a literal line feed to sed.

```
sed $'s/<br>/\\\n/g'
```